# CORS XMLHttpRequest request origin and referer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

In my angular app,  XMLHttpRequest request header includes origin and referer and is probably culprit of error messages '''No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://repish:3001' is therefore not allowed access.'''

```
Origin: http://repish:3001
Referer: http://repish:3001/
```

How do I add domain name to origin and referer ? And when I do the [same](https://passwd.me/api/1.0/get_password.txt?type=random&length=12&charset=LOWERCASEALPHANUMERIC) from my Win PC I don't see origin and referer in the request at all and it works fine?

Comment: You don't change those headers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your web application but on your server. If your server runs on the same domain as your web application there is no problem, but if it is not, you need to allow requests from another domain. (I assume you are developing and your server runs on your 'Win PC', which is why it works from there but not from any other device.

You should add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response on your server if you want to be able to use the result of your request. If not the browser will block it for security reasons.

This header should have the value of the domain where your request from or `*` to allow requests from any domain.

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" is present on server.

Comment: I instralled chrome extension Allow-Control-Allow-Origin and I am getting correct response now. and Origin/Referer are now: Origin:http://evil.com/
Referer:http://repish:3001/